# How to update an array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a array which is in a item in the collection of mongoose. This maybe obscure so here is my code.

```
 const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       name: String,
    });

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [itemSchema],
});
```

These are the schema

```
List.findOne({name:listTitle},function (err, list) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        list.items.push(item)
        res.redirect(`/${listTitle}`)
      }
    })
```

This is the code for which I am trying to update that items array in the List collections.

It does not shows me any error in the console but It doesn't updates the array.

Any Suggestions??

Comment: Could you please share your collection structure. Also I see only findOne method, I do not see update method. How do you expect your code will update array?

Comment: The instructor in udemy web development bootcamp used this way. They did not used update method

Comment: Aha, I see list.items.push(item)

Comment: What is `item`? Is it exists in your code?

Comment: item is a a object based on itemSchema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly go for :-

> [collection.findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

It will find the doc based upon your condition and then will make update to it.
While updating you need to use this $push operator to push elements to an array.

```
List.findOneAndUpdate({name:listTitle}, {
         $push: {
              items: item
          }
      }, function (err, list) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.redirect(`/${listTitle}`)
      }
    })
```

Comment: Happy to help you out! It would be great if you also upvote this.

Comment: I upvoted it but as my reputation is below 15 it is not recorded.